# Sum of finite differences.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, discrete-mathematics

There is a given function:
$$y:\mathbb{Z}_{\ge 0}\rightarrow \mathbb{R},$$
and finite difference operator $\Delta$ defined in following way:
$$\Delta^{0}y(x)=y(x)$$
$$\Delta^{1}y(x)=y(x+1)-y(x)$$
$$\Delta^{k+1}y(x)=\Delta(\Delta^{k})y(x)$$

> Write $F(x)=\Delta^{0}y(x)+\Delta^{1}y(x)+...+\Delta^{k}y(x)$ in nice form. In particular evaluate $F(0)$

By writing "nice form" I mean something that is analogous to equation $y^{0}+y^{1}+...+y^{k}=\frac{1-y^{k+1}}{1-y}$

Finite difference operator is an analogy of derivative. In case of derivatives it may be associated a polynomial. Is it possible here, in discrete mathematics?

After few transformations i get
$$\Delta F(x)-F(x)=\Delta^{k+1}y(x)-y(x)$$

Now i wonder about usage of Z-transform.

I will be grateful for any helpful answer.

Comment: It does not appear that there is a clear question here.  Is there something specific you want to ask about?

Answer (score 1):

I do not know if this is what you want. Note that the solution of the difference equation 
$$(I-\Delta) z(x)=y(x)$$
is
$$ z(0)=C, z(x)=C2^{x}-\sum_{i=0}^{x-1}2^{x-1-i}y(i),x\ge1. $$
Write
$$ (I-\Delta)^{-1}y(x)=\bigg\{\begin{array}{ll}C&\text{ if }x=0,\\
C2^{x}-\sum_{i=0}^{x-1}2^{x-1-i}y(i)&\text{ if }x\ge1.\end{array} $$
So
\begin{eqnarray}
(I-\Delta)F(x)&=&(I-\Delta)(\Delta^{0}+\Delta^{1}+...+\Delta^{k})y(x)\\
&=&(I-\Delta^{k+1})y(x)
\end{eqnarray}
and hence
$$ F(x)=(I-\Delta)^{-1}(I-\Delta^{k+1})y(x)=(I-\Delta^{k+1})(I-\Delta)^{-1}y(x). $$
Therefore
$$ F(0)=(I-\Delta^{k+1})(I-\Delta)^{-1}y(0)=(I-\Delta^{k+1})C=C-\Delta^{k+1}C=C. $$